# OData Filter for child items

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, odata

I am trying to code a small app with Python 2.7 for my Insightly account to receive all contacts with the tag "test".

I used the provided code samples for experimentation and it works really well but only for the top level elements.

```
contacts = i.getContacts(top=200) # returns the top 200 contacts
contacts = i.getContacts(orderby='FIRST_NAME desc', top=200) # returns the top 200 contacts, with first name descending order
contacts = i.getContacts(top=200, skip=200) # return 200 records, after skipping the first 200 records
contacts = i.getContacts(filters=['FIRST_NAME=\'Brian\''])    # get contacts where FIRST_NAME='Brian'
```

I would like to be able to get all contacts with the TAG_NAME "test".

```
contacts = i.getContacts(filters=['TAG_NAME=\'test\'']) #does not work
```

I did not find any way to achieve my goal and I would be very grateful if you could help me! :)

The response body format:

```
{
  "CONTACT_ID": 1,
  "SALUTATION": "sample string 2",
  "FIRST_NAME": "sample string 3",
  "LAST_NAME": "sample string 4",
  "BACKGROUND": "sample string 5",
  "IMAGE_URL": "sample string 6",
  "DEFAULT_LINKED_ORGANISATION": 1,
  "DATE_CREATED_UTC": "2014-09-03 02:36:08",
  "DATE_UPDATED_UTC": "2014-09-03 02:36:08",
  "VISIBLE_TO": "sample string 9",
  "VISIBLE_TEAM_ID": 1,
  "VISIBLE_USER_IDS": "sample string 10",
  "CUSTOMFIELDS": [
    {
      "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "sample string 1",
      "FIELD_VALUE": {}
    },
    {
      "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "sample string 1",
      "FIELD_VALUE": {}
    },
    {
      "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "sample string 1",
      "FIELD_VALUE": {}
    }
  ],
  "ADDRESSES": [
    {
      "ADDRESS_ID": 1,
      "ADDRESS_TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "STREET": "sample string 2",
      "CITY": "sample string 3",
      "STATE": "sample string 4",
      "POSTCODE": "sample string 5",
      "COUNTRY": "sample string 6"
    },
    {
      "ADDRESS_ID": 1,
      "ADDRESS_TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "STREET": "sample string 2",
      "CITY": "sample string 3",
      "STATE": "sample string 4",
      "POSTCODE": "sample string 5",
      "COUNTRY": "sample string 6"
    },
    {
      "ADDRESS_ID": 1,
      "ADDRESS_TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "STREET": "sample string 2",
      "CITY": "sample string 3",
      "STATE": "sample string 4",
      "POSTCODE": "sample string 5",
      "COUNTRY": "sample string 6"
    }
  ],
  "CONTACTINFOS": [
    {
      "CONTACT_INFO_ID": 1,
      "TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "SUBTYPE": "sample string 2",
      "LABEL": "sample string 3",
      "DETAIL": "sample string 4"
    },
    {
      "CONTACT_INFO_ID": 1,
      "TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "SUBTYPE": "sample string 2",
      "LABEL": "sample string 3",
      "DETAIL": "sample string 4"
    },
    {
      "CONTACT_INFO_ID": 1,
      "TYPE": "sample string 1",
      "SUBTYPE": "sample string 2",
      "LABEL": "sample string 3",
      "DETAIL": "sample string 4"
    }
  ],
  "DATES": [
    {
      "DATE_ID": 1,
      "OCCASION_NAME": "sample string 1",
      "OCCASION_DATE": "2014-09-03 02:36:08",
      "REPEAT_YEARLY": true,
      "CREATE_TASK_YEARLY": true
    },
    {
      "DATE_ID": 1,
      "OCCASION_NAME": "sample string 1",
      "OCCASION_DATE": "2014-09-03 02:36:08",
      "REPEAT_YEARLY": true,
      "CREATE_TASK_YEARLY": true
    },
    {
      "DATE_ID": 1,
      "OCCASION_NAME": "sample string 1",
      "OCCASION_DATE": "2014-09-03 02:36:08",
      "REPEAT_YEARLY": true,
      "CREATE_TASK_YEARLY": true
    }
  ],
  "TAGS": [
    {
      "TAG_NAME": "sample string 1"
    },
    {
      "TAG_NAME": "sample string 1"
    },
    {
      "TAG_NAME": "sample string 1"
    }
  ],
  "LINKS": [
    {
      "LINK_ID": 1,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ROLE": "sample string 1",
      "DETAILS": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "LINK_ID": 1,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ROLE": "sample string 1",
      "DETAILS": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "LINK_ID": 1,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_PROJECT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "ROLE": "sample string 1",
      "DETAILS": "sample string 2"
    }
  ],
  "CONTACTLINKS": [
    {
      "CONTACT_LINK_ID": 1,
      "FIRST_CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_CONTACT_ID": 2,
      "RELATIONSHIP_ID": 3,
      "DETAILS": "sample string 4"
    },
    {
      "CONTACT_LINK_ID": 1,
      "FIRST_CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_CONTACT_ID": 2,
      "RELATIONSHIP_ID": 3,
      "DETAILS": "sample string 4"
    },
    {
      "CONTACT_LINK_ID": 1,
      "FIRST_CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "SECOND_CONTACT_ID": 2,
      "RELATIONSHIP_ID": 3,
      "DETAILS": "sample string 4"
    }
  ],
  "EMAILLINKS": [
    {
      "EMAIL_LINK_ID": 1,
      "EMAIL_ID": 2,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1
    },
    {
      "EMAIL_LINK_ID": 1,
      "EMAIL_ID": 2,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1
    },
    {
      "EMAIL_LINK_ID": 1,
      "EMAIL_ID": 2,
      "CONTACT_ID": 1,
      "ORGANISATION_ID": 1,
      "OPPORTUNITY_ID": 1,
      "PROJECT_ID": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python, but from your payload, the Tags is a collection properties. So you cannot simply use $filter=Tags eq '...'. You should use lambda operations any/all for collection properties. For simple usage of any/all, please take a look at [OData tutorials - lambda](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#lambda)